# Facebook like button, locale not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

The user can change language on my webpage and I wish to change the text of the fb like button according to the current language. I use the iframe method and have read the documentation from fb but this is not working:

```
<iframe
  src='http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?locale=en-US&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=80&amp;action=recommend&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=10'
  scrolling='no' frameborder='0'
  style='border:none; overflow:hidden;
  width:80px; height:80px;'
  allowTransparency='true'></iframe>
```

I have set html lang='en-US' and locale=en-US in the src above but still the text display in my windows locale language.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If i remember right it (the locale= in the iframe address) should be en_US not en-US.

-michael

Comment: My locale code of the iframe version of the Like button is not working either, but I am using the correct `en_US` value. It worked for some time, but some days ago it started showing the spanish version of the button, and I did not change anything. Anyone experimenting a similar issue?

Comment: maybe you are logged into facebook with an account that has spanish as default language?

Comment: @Michael please mention me in the comments so that I am notified. Yes, you are right, but that's the reason why I use locale, I want the text to be displayed always in english, not the default. Also, I am pretty sure I was also logged in when some days ago it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a complete listing of all the locales supported by Facebook here:

http://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml

Good luck!

Comment: When I open the page up in Firefox I get an XML-document so if you get a blank page your browser probably doesn't display XML in the browser window. I that case, try a different browser or just right-click and download the file.

Comment: as of May 2017, Facebook removed this file from their servers. I could not find where the XML file went or if it's just gone.